# How to include header directory in makefile

Tags: makefile, contiki

```
    ### Compiler arguments
#CC = gcc
gcc -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121/include/jni.h
CFLAGSNO = $(EXTRA_CC_ARGS) -Wall -g -I/usr/local/include -DCLASSNAME=$(CLASSNAME)
CFLAGS   += $(CFLAGSNO)
```

When I tried entering this into makefile I was getting this error:

> make TARGET=cooja clean 
>   ../../../platform/cooja/Makefile.cooja:74: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.
>   Process returned error code 2

I am having problem with this line:
gcc -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121/include/jni.h

As per the instructions from other post I followed these instructions:

Fixing the issue

You can fix this by changing the Spaces to actual Tab characters. I used vim to repair my file. Simply open it:

```
$ vim makefile
```

And then run this command within:

```
:%s/^[ ]\+/^I/
```

This will substitute all the lines that begin with 1 or more Spaces with an actual Tab.

But still not working
How can I include this into makefile?

Comment: Is it your full `Makefile`? How did you try use `gcc` in your `Makefile`?

Answer (score 0):

Does your editor use spaces instead of tabs?
GNU Make requires real tab characters in its Makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

You can link the header with -I flag. for example -Icurl/, it will include all the header in that directory.

Sample way:

```
INCLUDE_DIR = app/curl/include
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -I$(INCLUDE_DIR )
```

**Answer to your question:**

ERROR: Makefile:8: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of
8 spaces?). Stop.

> This is the classical problem. Makefile accepts only tab indentation
>   with 4 space not 8. Change the setting of editor what you use to set the tab
>   width to 4, this will resolve your problem.

Comment: The comment "Makefile accepts only tab indentation with 4 space not 8. Change the setting of editor what you use to set the tab width to 4, this will resolve your problem" is not correct.  Make requires that recipe commands be indented with an actual TAB character as the first character on the line, not with space characters.  The _width_ shown by your editor when it displays a TAB character is utterly irrelevant: it can show 1 space, 2 spaces, 4 spaces, 5 spaces, 8 spaces, 9 spaces... all that matters is that the first character be a TAB.

Comment: @MadScientist: Still am having issues